# Service fabric fails to roll back application when deployment fails

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a 3 node cluster for service fabric where the deployment is stuck for 10hr on the third node. Looking at the SF explorer we saw that there is wrong SQL creds being passed hence the deployment is stuck.

1) Why is SF recognizing it at a "warning" rather than an "Error"

2) Why is it stuck and not doing a roll back?

3) Is there extra setting I need to do so it does auto rollback sooner?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it rollback when the deployment fail, but it will depend on the parameter you pass for the upgrade, like FailureAction, UpgradeMode and Timeouts.

**UpgradeMode** values can be:

- **Monitored**: Indicates that the upgrade mode is monitored. After the cmdlet finishes an upgrade for an upgrade domain, if the health of the upgrade domain and the cluster meet the health policies that you define, Service Fabric upgrades the next upgrade domain. If the upgrade domain or cluster fails to meet health policies, the upgrade fails and Service Fabric rolls back the upgrade for the upgrade domain or reverts to manual mode per the policy specified on FailureAction. ***This is the recommended mode for application upgrades in a production environment***.
- **Unmonitored Auto**: Indicates that the upgrade mode is unmonitored automatic. After Service Fabric upgrades an upgrade domain, Service Fabric upgrades the next upgrade domain irrespective of the application health state. This mode is not recommended for production, and is only useful during development of an application.
- **Unmonitored Manual**: Indicates that the upgrade mode is unmonitored manual. After Service Fabric upgrades an upgrade domain, it waits for you to upgrade the next upgrade domain by using the Resume-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade cmdlet.

**FailureAction** is the compensating action to perform when a *Monitored upgrade* encounters monitoring policy or health policy violations.  The values can be:

- **Rollback** specifies that the upgrade will automatically roll back to the pre-upgrade version.
- **Manual** indicates that the upgrade will switch to the UnmonitoredManual upgrade mode.
- **Invalid** indicates that the failure action is invalid *and does nothing*.

Given that, if the upgrade is not set as **Monitored** for *UpgradeMode* and **Rollback** for *FailureAction*, the upgrade will wait a manual action from the operator(user).

If the upgrade is already set to these values, the problem can be either:

- **The health check and retries are too long, preventing the upgrade to fail quickly, an example is when you HealthCheckDuration is too long or there are too much delay between checks.**
- The old version is also failing

The following docs give all details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-parameters